# Download Jar file from private GitHub repo in Java

Tags: java, github

I have 3 private GitHub repos, using Java, I would like to login to my account, and download a jar file from the RAW section of the repo. A simple task if the repos were public. But not so when private.

I have thought about using Apache2's HttpClient. However I have no clue (and googling didn't help either) how GitHub's auth is laid out.

I thought there might be some kind of library for GitHub in Java, but the only Lib I can find doesn't allow downloading of files ([here](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core)). Only logging in to the GitHub auth and pushing commits/fetching repos, etc. Which isn't what I am looking to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Since I can't create an answer.
Using the API [here](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github)

You can create a download service and download the repo. I've not worked out how yet, but I'm pretty sure it's possible, and I will update this answer once I've done it. I need to grab the "IRepositoryIdProvider"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache common's HttpClient library to give better control of the credentials/cookies/auth stuff to allow you to get the access. I think that is the problem, right?

Comment: I don't think that would work, a quick bit of googling came up with no results when trying to find out about GitHub's authentication layout.

Comment: It can do anything a browser can do (not talking UI or running javascript or that stuff).

Comment: I meant, GitHub's auth layout isn't public. So logging in and fetching a file wouldn't be possible. I couldn't find anything about the layout when searching for it.

Comment: What? What's the link?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core

I compiled it and am browsing it currently, nothing about pulling files from the Repo. Although it allows the option to download the entire repo, and then I can iterate through the files to get the correct one and delete the rest...

Comment: That is the eclipse git plugin you linked to...? What the hell.